# How to call IoT Central Device Bridge from Power Apps using Power Apps Custom API?

Tags: swagger, azure-functions, powerapps

I am trying to build a low-latency multi-user IoT asset data simulator and have tried different approaches, like bespoke HTML5/JSS apps, Node-Red flows with m-dashboards and PowerApps.

I have experimented with setting up a Power App sending data periodically to a Power Automate flow, where the Flow is directly assigned to the Power App (connection set up from within Power Apps). The called Power Automate flow then sends/calls the IoT Central Device Bridge in turn.

The Device Bridge is merely an Azure Function (with a Key Vault). In the article (https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-azure-functions-in-powerapps/) I read about a way to call an external API directly from the Power App.

So, what I would like to do is to call the IoT Central Device Bridge function directly from my Power App and loose the Flow intermediate part that substantially slows data throughput down.

Reading the article one needs the Swagger file, describing the functions API, to set this up in the Power App as a Custom API. How do I retrieve and use the Swagger file for my function in my Power App?